# How to submit drag and drop images without Ajax to servlet?

Tags: javascript, forms, html, servlets, drag-and-drop

I've an array of images got from drag and drop using HTML5 and previously was submitting those through ajax. 
But now I want to send these in a form WITHOUT using ajax.
What would be the approach? thanks in adv.!!

```
function upload(file) { // image file from drag n drop 

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "uploadServlet", true); 
    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the options would be to look into canvas, since you specify HTML5.
This is also supported on mobile devices.

You would then load an image into the canvas, and then have canvas output the imagedata.

This imagedata (as base64, or png, or...) could then be the value of a hidden input-field inside a form like this:
`document.getElementById("hiddenInputField").value=canvas.toDataURL("image/png");`

If you like this approach I'm shure we can find some working examples or custom code for you.

Good luck!